How to remove or hide string 'items' on Wordpress mini-cart side pane?
Past three hours I'm struggling to find a solution to get rid of string 'items' in mini-cart side pane on my WordPress site.
The reason is to unable to dynamically translate '1 item', '2 items' etc. to my native language.
Is there a simple or any way to remove or hide 'items' string?


It is very tricky as far as I noticed. You can find the file mini-cart.php and its hooks in woocommerce/template/cart. Try using this action hook 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart_contents', but you really need to clear cache (or also close window and restart to see your change!)

That didn't work.
I tried to add filters to functions.php, also tried to change cart.php and mini-cart.php file, restarted my browser, cleared my browser cache, cookies and settings, but seemed like just nothing happened, nor changed. It just stayed as it is and that's it.

Maybe if you share your HTML structure from your dev tools, we might help

structure:
/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyfour/functions.php
/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyfour/woocommerce/cart/cart.php
/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyfour/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php
functions.php added content:
function init_msg() {
echo 'Fired on the WordPress initialization';
}
add_action( 'init', 'init_msg');
function woocommerce_before_cart_hook()
{
echo 'woocommerce_before_cart_hook';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'woocommerce_before_cart_hook', 10, 6 );

working:
function init_msg() {
echo 'Fired on the WordPress initialization';
}
add_action( 'init', 'init_msg');
not working:
function woocommerce_before_cart_hook()
{
echo 'woocommerce_before_cart_hook';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'woocommerce_before_cart_hook', 10, 6 );
At least I got following message in console.log: Object { code: "invalid_json", message: "The response is not a valid JSON response." }

seems this is the case: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hooks-on-cart-and-checkout-page-not-working/
since WC8.3, the cart and checkout page are now based on blocks. This breaks the whole action and hooks principle. In short, the hooks mentioned above are no longer available in the blocks version.

I don't know why, but I think you would be better using a css solution for this. If you can share an image of your HTML structure in dev tools

You can also try this filter add_filter( 'gettext', 'your_function', 9999, 3 ); check this kind of answer link

I used your suggestion, but that wouldn't work either.
I used browser dev tools to determine what files was read and ended onto 'title-frontend.js', where 'items' string is stored.
Thanks for your suggestions and willingness to help me!:)

FINALLY!!!!!!!
After crawling about 1.5 days I managed to change string 'items' by editing file 'title-frontend.js' content in '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/client/blocks/mini-cart-contents-block/' directory.
The main reason with not changing text was the browser cache, which has to be flushed.

Glad you found your solution. Never give up always keep trying!
